# How I get android/data/"package name"/

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file

```
File filePath = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
```

But i return only /data, so where is /data is located and how i get andrid/data/"package_name"/

Comment: getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: Thank you for response mate, where i use getFileDir() and getExternalFilesDir(), if i use with Environment then it didn't show any function and if i used alone then it didn't exist.

Comment: I get the answer, but I feel like it's unconvensional like - File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Android/data/com.rigup.memest/files/Download/"+VideoName);

Comment: ???? What are you doing? You should only look at absolute path of getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir(null). Please tell their values first. You dont need Environment but a Context. In which class did you try them?

Comment: Yes, you're right I'm using different class and I have to use context. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is not the write way of getting the package name from your data folder but this can be used as a temporary solution:

```
File file=getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
```

Thanks to @blackapps for making the solution more simple.

Comment: Thank you soo much, with the help of your code my project is working fine..

Comment: I have updated my answer.You can add child by putting comma.Example:File file=new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),"/Download"+VideoName)

Comment: Then do it right: `File file=new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "Download/"+VideoName)`.

Comment: `File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());` That would be only: `File file = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();`.

Comment: Yes you both were right! I run your code blackapps and Danish. And again thanks for so fast reply and efficient answer. I'm trully grateful.

Answer (score 1):

- I will describe here which method returns which path.

| Methods | Output Path |
| --- | --- |
| Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory() | /data/cache |
| Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() | /storage/emulated/0 |
| CONTEXT.getExternalCacheDirs()[0] | /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/cache |
| CONTEXT.getExternalMediaDirs()[0] | /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/YOUR_PACKAGE |
| CONTEXT.getExternalFilesDir("DIR_NAME) | /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/files/DIR_NAME |
| CONTEXT.getFilesDir() | /data/user/0/YOUR_PACKAGE/files |
| CONTEXT.getCacheDir() | /data/user/0/YOUR_PACKAGE/cache |